# How to find all Permissions used in my React Native App?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, permissions

I am trying to find out all the permissions asked by my RN App. So I can remove those which are not really used anywhere. As my RN App works with sensitive user data I don't want to raise red flags when it is published on App Store and Play Store.
Any suggestions?